# Access windowsauthentication SQL Server 2008R2 after Domain change

Tags: windows-authentication, sql-server-2008-r2

When I installed the SQL Server 2008R2 on the windows server, the computer was not in a domain.

After I installed it, now someone moved the server into a domain.

Problem is: the server can not be accessed anymore, since it is set to windows authentication, the former accounts do not exist anymore, sa is disabled (not set).

Is there any way to change which windows accounts have admin rights to the SQL Server somehow, or do I need to reinstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a domain policy that removed the local Windows logins?  If not the logins should still be there and be usable.

If the SQL Instance is in Windows only mode, and there are no local accounts which have admin rights to the SQL Server, you'll need to reinstall the instance to get into the SQL Server.